# Convert word to pdf on Python without MS Word or Libre Office and on deployed Heroku app (Django)

Tags: python, django, pdf, heroku, ms-word

I want to convert a .docx file to .pdf file as part of a big project that I am working on. The only problem is that I work on widows and the project is deployed on Heroku which is Linux based. My locally tested library, packages don't work on deployed version since most of them use Word or Libre Office. Please help me with a library or code package or anything that I can implement in Python where I provide the input file as docx and want the output file to be a pdf doc.

Sample input and output file:

```
input = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, doc_name+'.pdf')
output = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, doc_name+'.docx')
```

Comment: You can try using `pandoc`, but honestly the easiest solution would be to pull the docx files down to your Windows system, convert them with Word, and ship the PDFs up to your web server.